# Data entry procedure in WPF using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm starting to learn MVVM and have seen how to bind the data list with the corresponding List<> in ViewModel. Now I need to realize a form that has different fields and, when the user clicks a button, I have to save data to a local database.

Which is the "most-MVVM" approach? I think to implement a `SaveItem(Item){}` method in ViewModel and, in code behind, for button click do something like

```
Item item = new Item();
item.field1 = txt1.Text;

...

item.fieldn = txtn.Text;
myViewModel.SaveItem(item);
```

I think there must be a cleaner way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Button` has a `DependencyProperty` of type `ICommand` called `CommandProperty`, and if that property is set the command will be invoked when the `Button` is clicked.

Typically in MVVM, one exposes a property of type `ICommand` (you need to create an implementation or take one from a framework) and binds to it in XAML like so:

```
<Button Content="My Button"
        Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
```

view-model:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
    public ICommand MyCommand 
    {
        get { … }
    }

    …
 }
```

Now you have no need for code-behind.

As for getting at the text that you want to save, again you want to favor databinding to your view-model rather than code-behind.

Instead of reading `TextBox.Text`, bind that property to your view-model.

view-model:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  …

    private string _myText;
    public string MyText
    {
        get { return _myText; }
        set 
        {
            _myText = value;
            // raise property change notification
        }
}
```

xaml:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Notice that we are using the `TwoWay` binding mode. That way changes in the viewmodel can be reflected in the `TextBox` (that's why you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`), and changes in the `TextBox` will be propagated to the view-model.

I also added the `UpdateSourceTrigger` setting because by default the view-model would only be updated when the `TextBox` loses focus. This way the view-model gets updated whenever the value changes. Use whatever makes sense in your application.